# Isomorphic Graph Proof (Degrees of Vertices)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I need to prove that two graphs (say, H and G) which are isomorphic and their vertices have the same degree.

So far, I have the summation of the degrees across all vertives is 2|E| and since if two graphs are isomorphic, then they must have the same number of edges. Therefore, each corresponding vertex in H and G must have the same degree. Is this sufficient? Thanks!

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you mean that "if two graphs are isomorphic, then their vertices have the same degree"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant; sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: cool. I presumed so in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not sufficient, because the last implication doesn't hold. $C_4$, the cycle on four vertices has 4 edges, as does a triangle with one additional edge sticking out from one of it's vertices. However those two graphs are not isomorphic, and the degrees fail to line up. In the later graph, there is a vertex of degree 3 and a vertex of degree 1, but in $C_4$ all vertices have degree 2. This approach is unlikely to work, because it doesn't use the "full power" of isomorphism.

Consider this approach: Let $\varphi:G\to H$ be an isomorphism. Then for $g,g'\in G$, we have that $$g\sim g'\iff \varphi(g)\sim\varphi(g')$$ This is the property you want to use to solve the problem. Try picking a vertex,$g\in G$ and assuming that $\varphi(g)$ and $g$ have different degrees and see what happens. Then take a vertex $h\in H$ and assume that $h$ and $\varphi^{-1}(h)$ have different degrees and see what happens. In both cases you should quickly get a contradiction.

Comment: Let me make sure that I understand your logic. If you say that φ(g) and g have different degrees, then the contradiction would be that g~g` and φ(g)∼φ(g′) which states that the 2 have the same degrees. The same applies for the h case? Thanks!

Comment: If you assume they have different degrees, then there is something that is adjacent to one of them but not the other. That something is the $g'$ in your later statement. Then you have a contradiction with the key property I note. This is an important detail to clarify.

Comment: and yes, the case with h works identically (and if you're clever, you can cover both cases at once!)

Comment: Let f=φ: G→H be an isomorphism, then for all g, g’ ∈G, we have g~g` <-> φ(g) ~ φ(g’).
Consider g∈G. and assume that φ(g) and g have different degrees, then there is something adjacent to one but not the other, namely is g’. However, this is a contradiction as g and φ(g) are adjacent to g’ and φ(g’) respectively. 

Now consider h∈H. Assume that h and φ^(-1)(h) have different degrees, then there is something that is adjacent to one but not the other, namely g’ However, this is a contradiction; h= φ(g), and (h= φ(g)) ~ (φ(g’)=h’) and g~g’. 

Does this make sense?

Comment: No, this is not good. $g$ and $\varphi(g)$ are in different graphs. The sentence "Consider $g\in G\ldots$ only makes sense if they are in the same graph. You want to say (by the pigeon hole principle) that there is a $k\in G$ such that $g\sim k$ but $\varphi(g)\not\sim\varphi(k)$